Is Miguel contradicting himself in this situation?
At Guggenheim Museum in Spider-Man Across The Spider-Verse (2023), Miguel battling a villain who was
transported from his home universe to Earth-65:

Miguel: Don't let him out! He'll disrupt the canon.

They took the battle above the museum where Police Helicopter joins them:

Pilot: Go to the ground.
Miguel: Will you get out of here?

It seems to Miguel contradicting himself by asking for help to prevent
the villain from escaping, but then requesting the police helicopter to leave.
Is Miguel contradicting himself in this situation?

The script is a little clearer. Miguel doesn't just want the Vulture not to escape, he's positively hunting him. The helicopter is getting in his way just at the moment that he was about to capture his prey.

Miguel bares his fangs, about to put this bird to sleep --
SHING! A BRIGHT LIGHT BLINDS THEM BOTH -- A POLICE HELICOPTER meddling
with Miguel’s kill!
CHOPPER COPPER: GO TO THE GROUND.
MIGUEL: Will you get out of here?!

Miguel isn't so much giving them an instruction that he expects them to follow, but rather verbally expressing his frustration that they've blundered into his territory.

I actually thought this was pretty clear from watching Miguel’s behavior.
